# php artisan optimize got stucked

Tags: laravel

after installing composer and laravel, I create new project by using commandline laravel new blog, and then I stuck at here. Please tell me what should I do? thanks.[image]

Comment: What happens after this ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? `php artisan optimize` it's a substitute for `composer dump-autoload -o` and It takes some time on windows to perform this operation. When I run this command using a linux based OS, it performs very fast.

Comment: on a average machine the optimization takes about 30 seconds at the first run with a fresh laravel install. So give it some time I guess this could take up to some minutes.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen nothing happens after that

Comment: I dont understand why? I take me more than 5 minutes  (I close it after that because I am impatient)

Comment: I was having the same issue on Laravel 5.4 and @Roscius's solution fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Cost me two days to figure out.

Mine is because the **APCu** extension. Change apc.enable_cli to 0 then it worked.

I am using php 5.5.28 and windows 10, however in windows 7 is fine with the same configuration. So check your php.ini configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, but because of xdebug running on the command line.  I disabled xdebug and it resolved the issue.

Comment: I was having the same issue on Laravel 5.4 and your solution fixed it. Thanks.